# Converting a formatted DB query from MySQL into MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have an issue converting a formatted DB query from MySQL into MySQLi. In MySQL, the following code produced a formatted list with each row forming a nicely formatted entry, all of them listed below each other. Three buttons would trigger the three different DB queries of different sets of data. On MySQLi, this code now produces a continuous stream of data without any line or paragraph breaks at all. Can someone help me out on how to get the formatting back?

I should add I'm a rookie programmer with minimal knowledge of MySQLi. Many thanks!

```
<?php

include 'tools/config.php';
include 'tools/opendb.php';

if(isset($_POST['button1'])){

echo "



";

$link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$query = "SELECT title, type, publication, date, pub_desc, link FROM publications WHERE status=\"P\" ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo "

{$row['title']} " .
"

{$row['pub_desc']}
" .
"{$row['publication']}, " .
"{$row['date']}, " .
"{$row['type']}


" ;
}

include 'tools/closedb.php';

}//if isset

if(isset($_POST['button3'])){

echo "



";

$query = "SELECT date, title, location, event FROM speeches ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo "

" . $row['title'] . "
";
echo "

" . $row['event'] . ", " . $row['location'] . "
";
echo "

" . date( "M Y", strtotime($row['date'])) . "
";
echo "
";
}

include 'tools/closedb.php';

}//if isset

if(isset($_POST['button4'])){

echo "



";

$query = "SELECT title, type, date, event, location, organizer FROM seminars ORDER BY date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo "

" . $row['title'] . "
";
echo "

" . $row['event'] . ", " . $row['organizer'] . "
";
echo "

" . $row['location'] . ", " . date( "M Y", strtotime($row['date'])) . "
";
echo "
";
}

include 'tools/closedb.php';

}//if isset

?>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you specify what environment this script is executed in (e.g. in a webbrower, in the console, and in which one...)?

Comment: Thanks! The script is part of a WordPress website and run within a page using a PHP plug-in. It ran fine until I had to make the transition to MySQLi. I’m currently testing it in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Since the output is displayed in a webbrowser, I assume the document you're `echo`ing to is HTML-formated.
As such, have you tried replacing your new lines in your `echo`s by a `<br>`?